# Create SQL Number that can be changed to specify the route order of deliveries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sequence

I'm using SQL server and linking to an Access Front-End. The project is for a delivery of goods. The user will add Sales and then check the best route using Google Maps (I don't have permission to use API keys). In any case, they will add an order and then decide which orders placed will be delivered 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc. They always leave from HQ so the route order is zero. I need to make sure there is no overlap of numbers so I can order by that number and total the distance that will be travelled based on that route.
Two users could be adding a record at the same time for the Day and Vehicle (I use a table that stores every day and every vehicle with an ID. So Van 1 - 01/01/2023 is ID:1. Van 2 - 01/01/2023 ID:2 etc. I use an Orders table in it's in here that I need to store the Route Order Sequence. the users will specify a better route by altering the selected record Up or Down in the list, altering the sequence.

So far I'm using VBA in Access to generate the numbers, but if I have two users attempting to add orders to the Same Vehicle/Date record, the VBA is failing. I don't want to prevent to users adding to the same Van/Date as this happens a lot. Plus I'm not convinced that even if I did do that, that my VBA is robust enough to provide the correct sequence. Ideally I want SQL to handle the number, not VBA.

Comment: What is your actual question here, as you don't ask anything. We can't answer your question if you don't have one to ask.

Comment: Sorry Larnu - my question is how can I create a sequential number that hold it's integrity that can be changed by a user. So if I have OrderHeaderID: 100  RouteOrder 0.  OrderHeaderID: 101 RouteOrder 1. OrderHeaderID: 102  RouteOrder =2. If the user changes a RouteOrder OrderHeaderID 101, RouteOrder = 2 then ID102 Route Order = 1. So it shuffles the routes so that the RouteOrders are always correct. If a user has moved the order to the bottom of the list, the one that was at the bottom has moved up one row.

Comment: [Edit] your question to actually ask your question.

Comment: when updating a record, how can I ensure that RouteOrder number is correct. That is, if there's 5 records each record will have a 0,1,2,3,4 or any 4,3,2,1,0. If the record I designate  is assigned a RouteOrder+1 (i.e. moving lower in the list) that the numbers beneath are updated correctly. Vice versa if a record I designate is RouteOrder - 1 that the Order Sequence maintains it's correct order, so that there is always a 4.3.2.1.0. and not 4,3,2,2,0 for example. Not sure I can express what I need in any more detail? There is actually a little more complication to this.

Comment: For example the Order breakdown into Sales and Collections. A sales must always be delivered first. So all sales will always be listed with a routeorder 0,1,2 and Collections 3,4,5. If a new sale is added, it would be RouteOrder 3, all Collections would be updated to RouteOrder +1, so they become 4,5,6

Comment: If the user selects a sale it can be adjusted to a new RouteOrder +1/-1 and moved up and down in the list. But it can't be moved to a routeorder that is the maximum sales order , otherwise it would appear below a collection (which is not allowed)

Comment: Those are comments, not an [edit].

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with a system that used a primary key in one table to generate a unique ID across systems. It leveraged the following table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderNumber]
(   [OrderId]  [int]      NOT NULL,
    [Assigned] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_OrderNumber_OrderId DEFAULT (GETDATE()),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_OrderNumber] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([OrderId] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY];
```

You will need to make sure that there is an initial value populated:

```
INSERT dbo.OrderNumber (OrderId) VALUES (0);
```

From there you will need to use a stored procedure containing a transaction to make sure that the value is unique. You can use the OUTPUT clause to capture the inserted value.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE
    dbo.GetOrderNumber
AS
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY  
        BEGIN TRANSACTION GetOrderNumbers;

        DECLARE @Temp TABLE (OrderId INT);

        INSERT INTO OrderNumber
        (   OrderId)
        OUTPUT
            inserted.OrderId
        INTO
            @Temp
        SELECT
            MAX(OrderId) + 1
        FROM
            OrderNumber;

        COMMIT TRANSACTION GetOrderNumbers;

        SELECT TOP 1 OrderId FROM @Temp;

    END TRY  
    BEGIN CATCH  

        IF (@@TRANCOUNT = 0)
            RETURN;

        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION GetOrderNumbers;
        THROW;

    END CATCH;  

END
```

You will need to add error handling in case there is an error retrieving the data.